# Prove that a relation is an equivalence relation

Tags: relations, symmetry

I have this relation: $S = \{ (x, y) \mid ((x - y) / 3) \in\Bbb Z \}$

I already proved that it's reflexive.
I don't know how to prove symmetry.

If I'm not mistaken it should be something like this:

H: $∀ x, y ∈ \Bbb Z: x \mathop{\rm S} y \iff ((x - y)/3) ∈ \Bbb Z$

T: $∀ x, y ∈ \Bbb Z: y \mathop{\rm S} x \iff ((y - x)/3) ∈ \Bbb Z$

but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Essentially you have to show that if $\frac{x-y}{3}$ is an integer, then so is $\frac{y-x}{3}$.  Do you see that that must be true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\frac{x-y}{3} \in \mathbb{Z}$,

It means $\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}, \frac{x-y}{3}=k$

and hence $\frac{y-x}{3}=-k$

Since $-k \in \mathbb{Z}$ as well.

Hence $\frac{y-x}{3} \in \mathbb{Z}$